# Xcode: Remove objects from NSMutableArray based on NSDictionary

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I am new to tableViews and dictionaries and i have a problem! 
In ViewDidLoad i am initializing many MutableArrays and i am adding data using NSDictionary. Example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
nomosXiou=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[nomosXiou addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mary",@"name",@"USA",@"country", nil]];
[nomosXiou addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Peter",@"name",@"Germany",@"country", nil]]; 

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.}
```

In a previous ViewController the **user selects a Country**. Based on that selection, how could i **remove from my arrays all the other entries???**

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that your code fragment has an error. It should read:

```
NSMutableArray *nomosXiou= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

There are a number of ways to do what you want, but the most straightforward is probably the following:

```
NSString *countryName;    // You picked this in another view controller
NSMutableArray *newNomosXiou= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *entry in nomosXiou) {
    if ([[entry objectForKey:@"country"] isEqualToString:countryName])
        [newNomosXiou addObject:entry];
}
```

When this is done `newNomosXiou` will contain only the entries in `nomosXiou` that are from the country set in `countryName`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the job:

```
NSMutableArray *nomosXiou = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *country = @"Germany"; // This is what you got from previous controller

// Some test data. Here we will eventually keep only countries == Germany
[nomosXiou addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mary",@"name",@"USA",@"country", nil]];
[nomosXiou addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Peter",@"name",@"Germany",@"country", nil]];
[nomosXiou addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"George",@"name",@"Germany",@"country", nil]];

// Here we'll keep track of all the objects passing our test
// i.e. they are not equal to our 'country' string
NSIndexSet *indexset = [nomosXiou indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    return (BOOL)![[obj valueForKey:@"country"] isEqualToString:country];
    }];

// Finally we remove the objects from our array
[nomosXiou removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexset];
```